# Erreur : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php

when i try to execute an update statement i got the following error :

```
Erreur : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Issy-les-Moulineaux ' where ssiphone_idstation=46' at line 1
```

my update statement is :

```
$bdd->exec("update ssiphone_stationdeservice set $cle='$element' where ssiphone_idstation=$id");
```

this is in a php code, THX in advance for your help :)

$cle and $element are in array, my code is :

```
 foreach($table1 as $cle => $element)
   {
   $bdd->exec("update ssiphone_stationdeservice set $cle='$element' where ssiphone_idstation=$id");
   }
```

now table1 is an array which contain the columns name of my table and its values :

```
$table1=array();
   $table1['ssiphone_etatstation']=$etat;
   $table1['ssiphone_commerce']=$commerce;
   $table1['ssiphone_stationdelavage']=$lavage;
   $table1['ssiphone_typescarburants']=$lescarburants;
   $table1['ssiphone_joursdelasemaine']=$jourssemaines;
   $table1['ssiphone_horaires ']=$this->horaires;
   $table1['ssiphone_telephone ']=$telephone;
   $table1['ssiphone_sensdecirculation ']=$this->sensDeCirculation;
   $table1['ssiphone_adresse ']=$this->adresse;
   $table1['ssiphone_ville']=$this->ville;
   $table1['ssiphone_departement']=$this->departement;
   $table1['ssiphone_nomstation ']=$this->nomStation;
```

Comment: Did you set values for `$cle`, `$element` and `$id`?

Comment: without the values of `$cle`, `$element` and `$id`, hard to say. I sincerely hope you are validating these inputs very thoroughly - SQL injection is just behind the corner.

Comment: Column names cannot contain `-` sign in their name. Your query design is wrong.

Comment: @furricane: wrong. `_` is a perfectly valid character in both column AND table names.

Comment: i don`t have - sign in my colums name :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your $cle variable isn't set, making the query look like:

```
... set ='Issy-les-moulineaux ' where ...
```

---

comment followup:

Change your code to look like this, then:

```
$query = "update ssiphone_stationdeservice set $cle='$element' where ssiphone_idstation=$id";
$result = $bdd->exec($query);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    print_r($bdd->errorInfo());
    die("Query: " . $query);
}
```

This way you have the complete query string in a variable you can inspect (e.g. by echoing out). Obviously there's something wrong with the query - but the mysql error string doesn't show the entire query, so you have to take measures to capture it.

Comment: i didn`t understand your answer, my values aren`t inserted manually but through an array, so i don`t have any intervention when the statement is executed :)

Comment: Hi, i think the problem is from a filed adress which contain ' caracter, my question is how to prevent this when insenting in database, thx :)

Comment: You're using PDO, so look into using prepared statements and bound parameters: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php. Those take care of any SQL metacharacters such as `'`. If you were using osmething like the mysql/mysqli functions, you'd use the mysql(i)_real_escape_string() function to do the same thing manually.